# Ethernet Network (eth0) not working after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, upgrade, ethernet

After upgrading my dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 the wired connection has stopped working. The option for Ethernet Network is greyed out and only wireless connections are available. The Ethernet connection is also not working in Windows 10. Running a diagnostic in Windows shows up as no Ethernet cable connected. I have tried the same LAN cable and setup on my laptop and it works.

My setup is by LAN cable to a NETGEAR Powerline extender which is connected to my Virgin Media NETGEAR Superhub. It works perfectly with my laptop.

The command `cat /etc/network/interfaces` shows up:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`ip link` shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:0f:41:d7:6e:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:10:b3:58:9e:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`ifconfig -a` shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:0f:41:d7:6e:4c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2505 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:249314 (249.3 KB)  TX bytes:249314 (249.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:10:b3:58:9e:a0  
          inet addr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3210:b3ff:fe58:9ea0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:256489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:257071 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:259396146 (259.3 MB)  TX bytes:30064247 (30.0 MB)
```

`dmesg | grep eth0` shows:

```
[    1.883397] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffc9000064a000, f8:0f:41:d7:6e:4c, XID 0c000800 IRQ 35
[    1.883404] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[  103.024707] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  104.161199] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: rtl_phy_reset_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 1).
[  104.163807] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[  104.163900] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

`lspci -v` shows for the Ethernet controller:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Onboard Realtek LAN
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at fe800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

I upgraded the network card driver using `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms` but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does your ethernet connection work in Windows? How is your ethernet cabled? Direct to modem/router/switch? Cheers, Al

Comment: Ethernet LAN cable is set up to a NETGEAR Powerline extender device which is connected to a Virgin Media NETGEAR Superhub wifi router. I tried it on Windows 10 on the same PC and it doesn't work. I tried the same LAN cable and setup on my laptop and it works using the cable. This points to not being a problem with the cable or setup. The problem must be with the PC, correct? Is it something in the BIOS that needs to change? It was working before the upgrade though. I have reset the router and factory reset the Powerline utility with no change.

Comment: Your "ip link" command shows no carrier, translated I believe it thinks that there's no cable connected. Please move this computer closer to the Netgear router, and use a DIFFERENT ethernet cable and connect it directly into one of the LAN ports. If it works, then there's something wrong with your original cable, or the Powerline stuff. Let me know. Cheers, Al